# How do i create 3 columns in html/css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create 3 columns each with a text centered both horizontally and vertically. I've tried the following:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

But for some reason I just get the 3 texts stacked on top of each other on the left side in my page.

Comment: You can see it in my page www.youben.dk in the bottom in frontpage..

Comment: Try bootstrap col-md-3 i think

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` on the container and an appropriate `width` setting on the children (as you did, but no `float`). In addition use `height: 100vh` (or 100% inside a container which has a defined height) and `align-items: center;` on the parent. This will center the content vertically. Horizontal centering inside the children can be achieved by using `text-align: center;`  on the children:

```css
.row {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.column {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```